# Installing SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation, 2019, windows-server, features

I am trying to install SharePoint 2010 with SQL Express 2008 on Windows Server 2019.

The pre-requisites installer runs, works and passes.

When I run the installer, it instantly errors telling me that some roles or features aren't installed.

Is there a list of all roles and features I need to enable to allow SharePoint 2010 to be installed on Windows Server 2019 please?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 is not supported nor tested on Windows Server 2019 so it could be anything. Why do you need to install such old SharePoint version on such new version of Windows? Can you post errors that installer is telling you?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 cannot be installed on Windows Server 2019. Max supported in 2012 R2 for which you need the SharePoint 2010 with SP2 ISO.

Comment: Is there documentations for this? Or is there really no chance in having SP2010 on a Windows Server 2019?